# How much gas does Openzeppelin whenNotPaused modifier cost?

Tags: openzeppelin

My question is if it's worth adding the whenNotPaused modifier.

It is not crucial to have this feature, so i'm wondering what is the gas cost of using it and if it is worth it?
By how much does a simple modifier like this increase the gas price?

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/security/Pausable.sol

Comment: The question is not clear to me. Is it crucial to have this feature? Yes if you want a Pausable smart contract, that is exactly what the contract you linked is used for. If you don't want a pausable contract, just avoid extending it in your smart contract. About gas cost, checking the value of a variable is one of the less expensive operation you can  do, so yes, it's cheap :)

Comment: Oh, and the gas price is determined by the client sending the transaction, not by the developer. What you can try to lower is the gas consumed, not it's price.